# Are achievements per Steam account or per character?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements

Are achievements in Skyrim per character or per account on steam? If the Achievements are per account is there a way I reset them?

When I say per character I mean can the Achievements I earn on one character be re-earned with another character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are per account.  Once you've earned an achievement with one character, you can't earn it again with another character as its now unlocked for your steam account.

And there is no known legitimate way of resetting steam achievements ([From here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4462-UIOB-0425)).

> Resetting Achievements
>   Unfortunately, achievements can not be reset at this time.

Comment: The same is true for Xbox Live achievements and PSN Trophies.

Comment: @nolonar With the difference that you can play the game on an infinite amount of accounts on consoles, and on only one account on steam.

Comment: @Kevin Ah, yes, that's true. But you still can't remove achievements from your profile on either platform. Still; you made your point.

Comment: You can reset cheevos with Steam Achievement Manager.

Comment: @kotekzot like I said, no known legitimate way :P